# Trouble Formatting Output "FOR XML"

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, reporting

I've been tasked with getting some data to be used with Instant Atlas from our database. And i've created a query that will return the data I want to show on the map. 
The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to format the XML correctly. 
I have been able to get hold of the schema (Instant Atlas) but I have no Idea how to apply the formatting during the execution on the SQL.

My query is as follows;

```
-- start of monthly pivot+ union

--Start of inner Pivot
DECLARE @year INT = 2015

SELECT 
[LAName] AS '@LA' , [1] AS 'Jan', [2] AS 'Feb', [3] AS 'Mar', [4] AS 'Apr', 
[5] AS 'May', [6] AS 'Jun', [7] AS 'Jul', [8] AS 'Aug', [9] AS 'Sep',
[10] AS 'Oct', [11] AS 'Nov', [12] AS 'Dec', 
[1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10] + [11] + [12] AS 'Total' , 1 as [sort]

FROM
(SELECT
L.LAName AS [LAName],
SUBSTRING(C.AgencyCode, 1, 3) AS [AgencyCode],
DATEPART(MONTH, ST.TransactionDate) as 'Date',
DATEPART(YEAR, ST.TransactionDate) as 'Year',
ST.TransactionId AS 'SyringeTransactions'
FROM SyringeTransaction AS ST
JOIN Client as C
ON C.ClientId = ST.ClientId
JOIN LocalAuthority as L
ON SUBSTRING(C.AgencyCode, 1, 3) = L.LAShortCode
WHERE SUBSTRING(C.AgencyCode, 1, 3) != 'XXX' AND C.Consent = 1 AND DATEPART(YEAR, ST.TransactionDate) = @year ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(count(SyringeTransactions) FOR SourceTable.[Date] IN
([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9] ,[10], [11], [12])

) AS Transactions_2015_Area
UNION
--end of innerPivot
--Start of outerPivot

SELECT 
[AgencyCode] AS '@LA' , [1] AS 'Jan', [2] AS 'Feb', [3] AS 'Mar', [4] AS 'Apr', 
[5] AS 'May', [6] AS 'Jun', [7] AS 'Jul', [8] AS 'Aug', [9] AS 'Sep',
[10] AS 'Oct', [11] AS 'Nov', [12] AS 'Dec', 
[1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] + [9] + [10] + [11] + [12] AS 'Total', 2 AS [sort]

FROM
(SELECT
C.AgencyCode AS [AgencyCode],
DATEPART(MONTH, ST.TransactionDate) as 'Date',
DATEPART(YEAR, ST.TransactionDate) as 'Year',
ST.TransactionId AS 'SyringeTransactions'
FROM SyringeTransaction AS ST
JOIN Client as C
ON C.ClientId = ST.ClientId
WHERE SUBSTRING(C.AgencyCode, 1, 3) != 'XXX' AND C.Consent = 1 AND DATEPART(YEAR, ST.TransactionDate) = @year ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(count(SyringeTransactions) FOR SourceTable.[Date] IN
([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9] ,[10], [11], [12])

) AS Transactions_2015_Agency

ORDER BY [sort], [@LA]
--end of outerPivot

-- end of pivot with union
FOR XML PATH('Geography'), ROOT('SyringeTransactions'), TYPE
```

The schema I need to match is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://data.instantatlas.com/atlas" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="AtlasData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Geography">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="FeatureList">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Feature">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="FilterValue">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:attribute name="for" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="ComparisonFeature">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="FilterList">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Filter">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ThemeList">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Theme">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Indicator">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Value">
                                  <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:attribute name="for" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                      </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="ComparisonValue">
                                  <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                      <xs:extension base="xs:float">
                                        <xs:attribute name="for" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                                      </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                              <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                              <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                              <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                              <xs:attribute name="precision" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                              <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                              <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="Property">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                              <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:decimal" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="data-source" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As Requested, this is exactly how the XML "Should" look when I'm done with it.

I've had to delete values for data protection reasons

```
-<Theme name="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" id="t0" xmlns="http://data.instantatlas.com/atlas">


-<Indicator name="All individuals" id="i0" date="2014-15 Q1" precision="0" type="numeric">

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">303</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyyy">633</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">240</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">109</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">2183</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyy">710</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyy">340</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">176</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyy">1525</Value>

<ComparisonValue for="1">NaN</ComparisonValue>

</Indicator>


-<Indicator name="All individuals" id="i0" date="2014-15 Q2" precision="0" type="numeric">

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">324</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">662</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">334</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">124</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">2008</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">545</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">194</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">161</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">1630</Value>

<ComparisonValue for="1">NaN</ComparisonValue>

</Indicator>


-<Indicator name="All individuals" id="i0" date="2014-15 Q3" precision="0" type="numeric">

<Value for="yyyyyyyyy">123</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">499</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyyy">298</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">101</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">1816</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">388</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">251</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">103</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">1298</Value>

<ComparisonValue for="1">NaN</ComparisonValue>

</Indicator>


-<Indicator name="Brief Interventions" id="i1" date="2014-15 Q1" precision="0" type="numeric">

<Value for="yyyyyyy">0</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyyyyy">0</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyy">444</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">28</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">12195</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">1239</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyyy">0</Value>

<Value for="yyyyyyy">8</Value>

<Value for="yyyyy">xxxx</Value>

<ComparisonValue for="x">NaN</ComparisonValue>

</Indicator>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of a valid XML? It is much easier to rebuild this...

Comment: I've edited my post with some of the "valid" XML 
The Y values correspond to place names

Answer (score 0):

Wihtout your actual tables it is hard to help you, but this will give you an idea, how you can build the structure you need.

I use *mock-up-tables* with dummy data (this is what you should have provided in order to create a *MCVE (minimal, verifyable, complete example)*.

```
DECLARE @indicator TABLE(RowID INT IDENTITY, Name VARCHAR(100),ID VARCHAR(100),[Date] VARCHAR(100),[Precision] INT,[Type] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @indicator VALUES('All individuals','i0','2014-15 Q1',0,'numeric')
                            ,('All individuals','i0','2014-15 Q1',0,'numeric');

DECLARE @values TABLE(indicatorID INT,forText VARCHAR(100),Value INT);
INSERT INTO @values VALUES(1,'yyyyyyy',100)
                         ,(1,'yyyyyyy',200)  
                         ,(1,'yyyyyyy',300)  
                         ,(1,'yyyyyyy',400)  
                         ,(1,'yyyyyyy',500)  
                         ,(1,'yyyyyyy',600)  
                         ,(1,'yyyyyyy',700)  
                         ,(1,'yyyyyyy',800)  
                         ,(1,'yyyyyyy',900)  

                         ,(2,'yyyyyyy',110)
                         ,(2,'yyyyyyy',210)  
                         ,(2,'yyyyyyy',310)  
                         ,(2,'yyyyyyy',410)  
                         ,(2,'yyyyyyy',510)  
                         ,(2,'yyyyyyy',610)  
                         ,(2,'yyyyyyy',710)  
                         ,(2,'yyyyyyy',810)  
                         ,(2,'yyyyyyy',910);
```

--The query

```
--Create without namespaces (otherwise each sub-select would get the namespace declaration
DECLARE @InnerXML XML=
(
    SELECT i.Name AS [@name]
            ,i.ID AS [@id]
            ,i.Date AS [@date]
            ,i.Precision AS [@precision]
            ,i.Type AS [@type]
            ,(
            SELECT v.forText AS [@for]
                  ,v.Value AS [*]
            FROM @values AS v
            WHERE v.indicatorID=i.RowID
            FOR XML PATH('Value'),TYPE
            )
    FROM @indicator AS i
    FOR XML PATH('Indicator'),TYPE
);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://data.instantatlas.com/atlas')
SELECT 'xxxxxx' AS [@name]
      ,'t0' AS [@id]
      ,@innerXML AS [*]
FOR XML PATH('Theme')
```

The result:

```
<Theme xmlns="http://data.instantatlas.com/atlas" name="xxxxxx" id="t0">
  <Indicator name="All individuals" id="i0" date="2014-15 Q1" precision="0" type="numeric" xmlns="">
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">100</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">200</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">300</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">400</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">500</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">600</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">700</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">800</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">900</Value>
  </Indicator>
  <Indicator name="All individuals" id="i0" date="2014-15 Q1" precision="0" type="numeric" xmlns="">
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">110</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">210</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">310</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">410</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">510</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">610</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">710</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">810</Value>
    <Value for="yyyyyyy">910</Value>
  </Indicator>
</Theme>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into this answer @shnugo I'll start working on this asap.

Comment: Hi @PhilipMather, is this issue solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: Not in the way that I had hoped. I decided to move away from a stream like approach and will manually build the XML using a HTTP handler with C#.
It will take a while to build the output but we'll probably only create a new output each week.